# How do I generate (autodoc) pages based on category in Sphinx?

Tags: django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm currently evaluating Sphinx for the documentation of my Django project. It consists of multiple apps tightly coupled into a project. One thing I'm trying to accomplish is generating pages of documentation *grouped by category*. I could do this all manually, but I'm hoping this could be automated.

Specifically, besides the regular generated autodoc documentation, I'd like pages in the documentation providing an overview of all...

- models
- middlewares
- views
- context processors
- signals
- test cases

from a typical app structure like

```
├── myapp
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── sometemplate.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── otherapp
    ├── context_processors.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── middleware.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── someotherfile.py
    ├── signals.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── othertemplate.html
    └── tests.py
```

and a (supposedly) docstring

```
class MyView(View):
    """Displaying ...

    Some info about this View.

    .. category::
       django_view

    """
```

rendering in documentation like

> #### Views
>
> **`myapp`.`views`.`MyView`**
>
> > Some info about this View.
>
> **`otherapp`.`views`.`OtherView`**
>
> > Some info about this OtherView.

I see that [**django-sphinx-autodoc**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-autodoc) will probably be of help in general about walking through the apps. Should I extend/modify django-sphinx-autodoc to do what I want? Would you advice some other approach to get this? Or is doing this all manually the only way?

Answer (score 0):

How about using subrepositories? You could create a new project where `myapp` and `otherapp` would be subrepositories parallel to the doc directory:

```
doc_proj/
   build/
   Makefile
   source/
   myapp/    (subrepository)
   otherapp/ (subrepository)
```

Comment: I don't see how this will generate documentation grouped by category. The location of the source files of the documentation don't change anything as to how Sphinx will generate pages. Is this an answer to another question?